# HTML Scraping in Php

Tags: php, html, screen-scraping

I've been doing some HTML scraping in PHP using regular expressions.  This works, but the result is finicky and fragile.  Has anyone used any packages that provide a more robust solution?  A config driven solution would be ideal, but I'm not picky.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947/how-to-implement-a-web-scraper-in-php#27109) thread - the question goes into a similar direction

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would recomend [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) after you have scraped the HTML from the page. It supports invalid HTML, and provides a very easy way to handle HTML elements.

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: can you give me example to click on any link on a given page?

Answer (score 5):

If the page you're scraping is valid X(HT)ML, then any of [PHP's built-in XML parsers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) will do.

I haven't had much success with PHP libraries for scraping. If you're adventurous though, you can try [simplehtmldom](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/). I'd recommend [Hpricot](http://code.whytheluckystiff.net/hpricot/) for Ruby or [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for Python, which are both *excellent* parsers for HTML.

Comment: If you're going to be parsing particularly sloppy HTML, make sure you don't use BeautifulSoup 3.1.x (use 3.0.x).  3.1.x uses htmllib as its parser, which is much less forgiving than 3.0.x's use of sgmllib.

Answer (score 5):

I had some fun working with [htmlSQL](https://github.com/hxseven/htmlSQL), which is not so much a high end solution, but really simple to work with.

Comment: late comment but I just found your answer via google.. i like it! :)

Comment: Does it work for you even now? It does not seem to work for me...

Answer (score 5):

I would also recommend 'Simple HTML DOM Parser.' It is a good option particularly if your familiar with jQuery or JavaScript selectors then you will find yourself at home.

[I have even blogged about it in the past.](http://blog.dougalmatthews.com/2008/08/html-dom-and-easy-screen-scraping-in-php/)

Answer (score 3):

Using PHP for HTML scraping, I'd recommend cURL + regexp or cURL + some DOM parsers though I personally use cURL + regexp. If you have a profound taste of regexp, it's actually more accurate sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I've had very good with results with the [Simple Html DOM Parser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) mentioned above as well. And then there's the  [tidy Extension for PHP](http://www.php.net/tidy) as well which works really well too.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use curl on my host 1and1.

http://www.quickscrape.com/ is what I came up with using the Simple DOM class!