# file_get_contents and div

Tags: php

What's wrong with my code?
I wish to get all dates from 
but my array is empty.

```
<?php
$url = "http://weather.yahoo.com/";
$page_all = file_get_contents($url); 

preg_match_all('#<div id="myLocContainer">(.*)</div>#', $page_all, $div_array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($div_array);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: It might be your code, it might be not. Please provide more debug otherwise you'll waste others time in wild goose chases.

Answer (score 0):

You want to parse a multiline content but you did not use multiline switch of REGEX pattern.
Try using this:

```
preg_match_all('#<div id="myLocContainer">(.*?)</div>#sim', $page_all, $div_array);
```

Please note that regular expressions is not suitable for parsing HTML content because of the hierachical nature of HTML documents.

Answer (score 0):

try adding "m" and "s" modifiers, new lines might be in the div you need.. like this:

```
preg_match_all('#<div id="myLocContainer">(.*)</div>#ms', $page_all, $div_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before messing around with REGEX, try *HTML Scraping*. This [HTML Scraping in Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120/html-scraping-in-php) might give some ideas on how to do it in a more elegant and (possibly) faster way.

Comment: There is a recent implementation of such a library (allowing to access elements via CSS etc) built on PHP 5.3, using some components of the upcoming Symfony 2. Note: It's still kind of unstable. http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/22/four-new-php-5-3-components-and-goutte-a-simple-web-scraper/

Answer (score 0):

```
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->Load('http://weather.yahoo.com/');
$doc->getElementById('myLocContainer');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to Excape Special Characters in your Regular Expression like the following

```
~\<div id\=\"myLocContainer\"\>(.*)\<\/div\>~
```

also Checkout wheather there is a newline problem or not as mentioned by @eyazici and @kgb

Answer (score -2):

Test your response before running the regex search.  Then you'll know which part isn't working.

Comment: file_get_contents can use a http stream wrapper, so it's not only for local files