# Extracting specific data from a web page using PHP

Tags: php, html, screen-scraping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML Scraping in Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120/html-scraping-in-php)

I would like to know if is there any way to get from a webpage a specific string of text wich is updated every now and then using PHP. I´ve searched "all over the internet" and have found nothing. Just saw that preg_match could do it, but I didn't understand how to use it.

imagine that a webpage contains this:

```
<div name="changeable_text">**GET THIS TEXT**</div>
```

How can I do it using PHP, after having used [`file_get_contents`](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to put the page in a variable?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Forget about the div name. LOL

Comment: The topic your looking for is "screen scraping".  More info here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/screen-scraping/info

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument), like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents( $url);

libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);

// A name attribute on a <div>???
$node = $xpath->query( '//div[@name="changeable_text"]')->item( 0);

echo $node->textContent; // This will print **GET THIS TEXT**
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the

> Simple HTML DOM Library

There is a little tutorial here:
http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/easy-screen-scraping-in-php-simple-html-dom-library-simplehtmldom-398/

That one is a screen scraping API that lets you feed html to it and then get parts of it in a jQuery similiar language.

Answer (score 0):

You’re talking about [data scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping): the act of extracting data from a human readable output. In your case this is whatever is between the `<div>` tags. Use [PHP DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php)’s extension to get to the tag you want and extract data. Google search for a PHP DOM tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
$delements= file_get_html('url will go here'); 

foreach($elements->find('element') as $ele) {

    //traverse according to your preferences

} 

//return or output
```