# Extract website html data using php

Tags: php, curl

i use this code to Extract website https://billing.te.eg/Arabic/BillStatus.aspx?Acc=A4000917512

but i have a error `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in index.php` 
and what i want to Extract it between span elemant like `<span id="SpanPhoneNumber" dir="ltr">02-26981106</span>` or `<span id="SpanCurrentBalance">19.30</span>`

```
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
//use curl to get html content
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
       return @curl_exec($ch);
}
$html=getHTML("https://billing.te.eg/Arabic/BillStatus.aspx?Acc=A4000917512",10);
// Find all images on webpage
foreach($html->find("img") as $element)
echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links on webpage
foreach($html->find("a") as $element)
echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use
`str_get_html()`
function on $html variable from sipmle_dom_html library:

```
$response=getHTML("https://billing.te.eg/Arabic/BillStatus.aspx?Acc=A4000917512",10);
$html = str_get_html($response);
```

when working with https pages you may also need to use inside your function:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: thanx i put it like you said but it's same error `Call to a member function find() on a non-object in `

Comment: do you think the problem from the website ? becouse i try now another link and working good .

Comment: Try $this->html->find

Comment: @anantkumarsingh i try it , show me this error `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`

Comment: Use DomDocument. for reference check link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567632/extracting-specific-data-from-a-web-page-using-php

Comment: @anantkumarsingh i try it and working good but with this site not work `https://billing.te.eg/Arabic/BillStatus.aspx?Acc=A4000917512` show me this error `Warning: file_get_contents(https://billing.te.eg/Arabic/BillStatus.aspx?Acc=A4000917512) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream`

Comment: you may need to add following fields:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
to work with https pages

Comment: yeah it's working now as well , now how i can get data by element `span` and `id` like `<span id="SpanPhoneNumber" dir="ltr">02-26981106</span>` or `<span id="SpanCurrentBalance">19.30</span>`