# How to get all the links from a .php page?

Tags: php, hyperlink, screen-scraping

I've opened a .php page from a website with bunch of hyperlinks on it. I want to copy them (their URLs) into a .txt file. Of course, I could do that manually, but there are too many of them, so I would want to do it somehow automatically.

Before I would do it this way: I would look into the page source, that is, its HTML code, and then parse it with some small script written specially for that. But this one is a .php page and all the links are piped in from a database on the server, I guess, rather than from the source code. Anyway, they are not in the page's HTML code.

I wonder if that is still possible. I believe it should be possible - all the links are displayed on my screen, they are all click-able and working, there should some way of capturing them somehow.

Comment: You can use the same script to parse the links. Did you try that?

Comment: If they dont show in the source, then they are added by javascript, not php

Comment: Have you tried [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all) ?

Comment: Maybe you'll find what you're looking for here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120/html-scraping-in-php?

Comment: using `file_get_contents()` you can also do it by the same script

Comment: @AmalMurali - They are not in the HTML code.

Comment: @HarryDenley - "Have you tried preg_match_all ?" - NO, I haven't. What should I do in order to start using it? Is it a special software or a programming language that I need to install first? How?

Comment: @user574632 - "...they are added by javascript, not php" - Thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: @brilliant im sure thats your issue, in which case none of these answers will help you. Can you confirm thats the case (that the links dont appear in the source), then i can help you

Comment: @user574632 - "Can you confirm thats the case" - I am confirming: they are NOT in the page's HTML source.

Comment: @brilliant ok, the you need a js enabled dom parser to get the info - what programming languages are you familiar with? EDIT if this is only for a few pages Dharmesh's answer is ideal

Comment: @user574632 - I am only familiar with AHK (www.autohotkey.com)

Comment: @user574632 "if this is only for a few pages Dharmesh's answer is ideal" - Thank you. I am trying to use his way now.

Comment: @user574632 - Thank you! Dharmesh's code did it so well indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understand is you want to do this from browser itself: in that case use chrome open debug panel (press F12) and got to console tab and paste following code and press enter, and then copy the list of links from console and put in txt file.

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<tags.length;i++) {
    console.log(tags[i].getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Comment: Make sure your console is filtered to all, and not debug. [See Image - Chrome](http://i.imgur.com/kxEil4x.png)

Comment: WOW!!! It worked just like that! Thank you. Can you, please, tell me what language is your code written in?

Comment: it's simple Javascript :)

Comment: Ah! I see. I didn't know that Chrome accepts Javascript. Thanks again!

Comment: @HarryDenley - Thank you! Do you know any resourse on the internet where I could learn how to use that console with Javascript?

Comment: I don't have any link to learn how to use console but if you know Javascript you can write any Javascript code in console and it will execute it.

Comment: @DharmeshPatel - Oh, I see, thank you. Guess it's about time I started learning Java - have already stumbled upon many cases when it's proved to be quite useful.

Comment: Java and Javascript are totally different. I think what you meant, from what's supplied in this thread, is that you think it's time to learn JavaScript.

Comment: @HarryDenley - Oh my! I didn't know they were two different things. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do.

Use php's CURL library to get the page as a string. Or better yet use `file_get_contents`

https://www.php.net/file_get_contents

`$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');`

Use the DomDocument library to build a html document. https://www.php.net/domdocument

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($homepage);
```

From here you can get all the `<a>` tags in the html and get the href elements. By Calling `$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");`

Then just iterate over the elements getting the href out.

```
foreach($elements as $el) {
    $link = $el->getAttribute("href");
    echo $link . "\n";
}
//untested code
```

You can then re-use the script on any page, just change the curl request.