# Getting data from an external webpage

Tags: php

What's the best way to get content from an external website via php?

Using php how do I go to webpage (ex: http://store.domain.com/1/) and scan the HTML coding for data that is found in between   (which is the letter C and E). what php method do I use?

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_phstats1_pname">C</span>
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_phstats2_pname">E</span>
```

then save "C" (the found string) to $pname

```
$_session['pname1'] = $pname1;
$_session['pname2'] = $pname2;
```

Comment: It's called screen scraping, and has been asked/answered many times on this site before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519920/screen-scraping-technique-using-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient method is:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/whatever.html');

$pos = str_pos($content,'id="c');
$on=0;
while($pos!==false)
 {
 $content = substr($content,$pos+4);
 $pos = str_pos($content,'"');
 $list[$on] = substr($content,0,$pos);
 $on++;
 $pos = str_pos($content,'id="c');
 }
```

Then all yours values will be in the $list array, the count of which is $on.

You could also do it in one line with one of the preg functions, but I like the old-school method, it's a nanosecond faster.

Comment: should it be 
$pos = str_pos($content,'<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_phstats1_pname">'); ? what would be the best way to do it separately instead of grouping all in a list array

Comment: No, it should be as it is, otherwise you will only get 1 result.

Comment: It's best to put them into an array and then just process them individually after, using for($run=0; $run<$on; $run++), and inside that loop $list[$run] will contain each ID.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use web page scraping technique. It can be done simply by using `HTML DOM Library` or with technologies like  `Node.js` and `jQuery`. You can find some useful tutorials regarding this [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-node-js-and-jquery/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20nettuts%20%28Nettuts%2b%29) and [here.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library/)

You may also see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947/how-to-implement-a-web-scraper-in-php) regarding implementing scraping using `PHP`

Answer (score 0):

i think you can actually use `file_get_contents("http://store.domain.com/1/");` to do an http request.

as far as parsing it, depending on how big your project is and how much effort you're willing to go, you can find an html DOM parser like here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ or simply search for `id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_phstats1_pname"` and take it apart piece by piece (not the recommended way of doing things).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by CURL. But you can just include the Simple HTML DOM Parser in your project. Its very easy to use and will serve your purpose.

The documentation is here. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/