# PHP Screen Scraping and Sessions

Tags: php, session, curl, screen-scraping

Ok still new to the screen scraping thing.

I've managed to log into the site I need but now how do I redirect to another page? 
After I login I'm trying to do another GET request on the page that I need but it has a redirect on it that takes me back to the login page.

So I'm thinking the SESSION variables are not being passed, how can I over come this?

Problem:

Even if I post the 2nd page URL it still redirects me back to the login page, unless I'm logged in already, but the screen scrape code is not allowing the SESSION data to be passed?

I found this code from [another screen scraper question here @stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947/how-to-implement-a-web-scraper-in-php)

```
class Curl {

    public $cookieJar = "";

    public function __construct($cookieJarFile = 'cookies.txt') {
        $this->cookieJar = $cookieJarFile;
    }

    function setup() {
        $header = array();
        $header[0]  = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
        $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
        $header[]   = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
        $header[]   = "Connection: keep-alive";
        $header[]   = "Keep-Alive: 300";
        $header[]   = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
        $header[]   = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
        $header[]   = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.

        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7');
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    }

    function get($url) {
        $this->curl = curl_init($url);
        $this->setup();

        return $this->request();
    }

    function getAll($reg, $str) {
        preg_match_all($reg, $str, $matches);
        return $matches[1];
    }

    function postForm($url, $fields, $referer = '') {
        $this->curl = curl_init($url);
        $this->setup();
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        return $this->request();
    }

    function getInfo($info) {
        $info = ($info == 'lasturl') ? curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL) : curl_getinfo($this->curl, $info);
        return $info;
    }

    function request() {
        return curl_exec($this->curl);
    }
}
```

Calling the class

```
include('/var/www/html/curl.php');
$curl = new Curl();

$url = "here.com";
$newURL = "here.com/newpage.php";

$fields = "usr=user1&pass=PassWord";

// Calling URL
$referer = "http://here.com/index.php";

$html = $curl->postForm($url, $fields, $referer);
$html = $curl->get($newURL);

echo $html; // takes me back to $url instead of $newURL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following lines do not use "$this" and $cookieJar isn't in local scope:

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar);
```

So it should look like:

```
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookieJar);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookieJar);
```

If that doesn't fix the issue try and only do the post:

`$curl->postForm($url, $fields, $referer);`

and not

`$curl->get($newURL)`

Then check if the cookie.txt file contains anything? Does it get created? Let us know the results as it's hard to quickly test your code without the actual URL being hit.

If it isn't creating a cookie.txt file than you can almost guarantee that the session isn't being kept between requests.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem as well as the cookies.txt file didn't have the correct permissions. Such a newbie mistake. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

maybe the example isnt correct .. but from the looks of it the domain is changing .. so here.com session wont exist on there.com

Comment: The SESSION should pass from here.com to there.com it's the same domain just a different page but just for example I used. Maybe I should change that

Answer (score 0):

The site is probably trying to store the session id in a cookie.  You have curl set up to use cookies via a "cookies.txt" file though.  So, my first thought would be - what's in the cookies.txt file?  Does the script have permissions to actually create that file?

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine by using $curl->get($newURL) instead of $curl->postForm($url, $fields, $referer);