# How to retrieve the title part of other web page like google or yahoo using php?

Tags: php, html

I want to retrieve the title of the cricinfo.com webpage. How to retrieve it using php. Please help me

Comment: See: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947/how-to-implement-a-web-scraper-in-php">How to implement a web scraper in PHP? - Stack Overflow</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it via a reg exp ::ducks::

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811616/how-to-retrieve-the-title-part-of-other-web-page-like-google-or-yahoo-using-php';
preg_match('~<title>(.*?)</title>~i', file_get_contents($url), $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something to get the source of the webpage.
Then look for the position of the `<title`> substring (call it start_index...add 7 to it because `<title>` is 7 chars long)).  Also look for the position of the `</title>` substring (call it end_index).
The title of that page is the substring bewteen start_index and end_index.