# Read/Get Contents and data from a website

Tags: php, mysql, web-scraping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement a web scraper in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947/how-to-implement-a-web-scraper-in-php)

I would like to retrieve some data from a website.
For example, I want to get some data from a supermarket website. I want to get the goods name, price, etc.. into mysql.
What should I do?? Using php or other language.
Do you have any tutorial pages provided?
I really have no idea.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) or just PHP function [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Also, read about [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: i have some research on curl..but still have no idea..
do u have any example?

Comment: Just try in google: "php curl begginer" there is tons of tutorials about this.