# Get contents of a div from a URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement a web scraper in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947/how-to-implement-a-web-scraper-in-php)
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I need to crawl through a page and get the contents of a particular div. I have php and javascript as my two main options. How can it be done?

Comment: have you possibly thought of perl and [WWW-Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a basic method to do it PHP and it returns the content in plain text. However you might consider revising the regex for your particular need.

```
<?php
  $link = file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com");
  $file = strip_tags($link, "<div>");
  preg_match_all("/<div/>(?:[^<]*)<\/div>/is", $file, $content);
  print_r($content); 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to get the contents of an url:

First Method:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
 Simple HTML DOM Parser
```

Second Method :

```
<?php

  $contents = file_get_contents("http://www.url.com");
  $contents = strip_tags($contents, "<div>");
  preg_match_all("/<div/>(?:[^<]*)<\/div>/is", $contents, $file_contents);

?>
```

Third Method:

```
`You can use jquery like Selectors :`
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

You can use SimpleDomParser as documented here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm
it requires PHP5+ though, but the nice thing is you can find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically with jQuery, if you have a `div` like the following:

```
<div id="cool_div">Some content here</div>
```

You could use jQuery to get the contents of the `div` like this:

```
$('#cool_div').text(); // will return text version of contents...
$('#cool_div').html(); // will return HTML version of contents...
```

If you're using PHP to generate the content of the page, then you should be able to get a decent handle on the content and manipulate it even before it's returned to the screen and displayed. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, you can try the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class and the **getElements()** function