# php - save whole webpage (HTML + CSS + Javascript)

Tags: java, php

lets say i have this url for webpage

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Newegg.com - HP ENVY 14-3010NR </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="js/swfobject.v1.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="message2OlderBrowser">
        <p>Newegg.com - A great place to buy computers</p>
        <p>If you are reading this message, </p>
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
</body>
</html>
```

i need a tool (written in PHP or java) to call function like

```
saveWebPage($url);
```

and in result i will have these files:

```
newegg.html
css/style.css
js/swfobject.v1.5.js
```

is there a tool or function like this ?

Comment: You want to look in to [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).

Comment: Are you confident the NewEgg AUP allows automated retrieval of their data?

Comment: no i used newEgg just for example

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947/how-to-implement-a-web-scraper-in-php