# scraping data from a website and storing within a variable

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

i want to grab certain values off a website when a username is put into an input box and then store these in a variable so i can use in a part of my website

the information i am trying to scrape is from the runescape highscores
http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/heroes.ws

now when a username is entered the url changes to this (username is Paulrat3)
http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/compare.ws?user1=Paulrat3

i want to grab the attack, strength, defence, constitution, magic, range, prayer and summoning levels and maybe store them in variables such as

$attack
$strength

etc

how can i do this?

Comment: This question has been asked before. Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947/how-to-implement-a-web-scraper-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte).

This is a web scraping tool written in PHP. Sounds like it would be perfect for your needs.